# Swift - Pasar datos entre vistas con controles personalizados

Tags: swift, uitableviewcontroller

Estoy haciendo una navegación entre views y pasando parámetros a través del segue.

La idea es la siguiente:

**ViewA** - Tiene un control (celda) personalizado, con un label y una imagen. Esta celda personalizada, tiene su propia clase llamada *RateCell*, que si contiene los @IBOutlet de sus respectivos controles (Label y Imagen)

**ViewB** - Es una vista tableview, donde cada cell tiene un Label y una imagen

La idea es que al hacer click en una celda cualquiera del ViewB, se pasen los datos a la celda personalizada del ViewA, pero no se como acceder al control personalizado en ViewA, ya que no me deja referenciarlo con @IBOutlet por ser un control Custom.

¿Cómo puedo acceder al control personalizado del ViewA para insertar los datos a dicho control?

Estoy comenzando con el desarrollo para swift.

Comment: Utiliza los protocolos para eso. Busca patrón `Delegate iOS` y verás que te salen muchos ejemplos

Comment: +1, protocolos es la mejor opción para esto.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la información, voy a documentarme sobre los delegados etc.

Comment: No, si las dos vistas están instanciadas en la misma clase no uses protocolos.
@mhergon Hay que evitar el uso de protocolos siempre que se pueda al igual que el notification center. Eso produce un código ambiguo. Es mejor en este caso crear dos clases de UIView y añadirle funciones para poder comunicar una con otra a través del controlador. Hay que respetar siempre que se pueda el patrón de diseño MVC.

Comment: @AlvaroRoyo hay que evitarlos, pero para muchos casos son inevitables nos guste o no

Comment: Claro claro por supuesto @mhergon pero en este caso no lo veo necesario

Comment: Una pregunta, viewA y viewB son 2 celdas de la misma tabla? o View A y B son 2 ViewController diferentes y cada uno tiene una tabla? Para la segunda opción estoy con @mhergon, delegado y en el DidSelect del B le pasa por el delegado la información a A

Answer (score 2):

Hola si son dos clases viewcontroller para pasar datos usas los segue, si es de viewA a viewB con el uso de segues y unas variables globales que reciban los valores lo puedes lograr.

Ejemplo:

```
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "showViewB" {
        let destino = segue.destination as! viewB //ViewControllerB
        destino.imagen = imagen // variable del viewB que recibe lo que le envias de viewA
        destino.texto = texto // variable del viewB que recibe lo que le envias de viewA

    }

}
```

Si es del viewB a viewA usas el unwind segue, funcionan casi de la misma manera.

```
    @IBAction func mostrarViewA(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let viewController = segue.source as! viewB

    imagen = viewController.imagen //variable de viewA que recibe los datos de viewB
    texto = viewController.text //variable de viewA que recibe los datos de viewB
    tablewView.reloadData()



}
```

Comment: "*casi de la misma manera*" <-- sería interesante saber cuál es la diferencia

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es pasar datos a otra clase, create dos variables en la view A llamadas imagen y titulo por ejemplo y o bien haces uso del didSet para controlar cuando cambian estos valores y recargar la tabla , o bien directamente pasas los datos a esta variable a través del segue y al entrar en la Clase A recargas la tabla.